# Laravel Forum Example

Tags: laravel, forum

Is there any tutorial or example for developing forum in laravel?
I would like to develop like this discourse demo [Discourse demo](https://try.discourse.org/) https://try.discourse.org/

Comment: Don't bite more than you can chew. ([How to](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)) ask simple questions for start.

Answer (score 1):

Try this course from Jeffrey Way which is easy to understand, and time efficient: [Let's Build A Forum with Laravel and TDD](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel).

> A forum is a deceptively complex thing. Sure, it's made up of threads and replies, but what else might exist as part of a forum? What about profiles, or thread subscriptions, or filtering, or real-time notifications? As it turns out, a forum is the perfect project to stretch your programming muscles. In this series, we'll work together to build one with tests from A to Z.